# Corrupted Cycles Rendered Frames

Tags: rendering

I render an animation with Cycles Render, Blender 2.78c. There are 2 scenes, one is rendered with the GPU (64 tiles) and the other (smoke) is rendered with the CPU (16 tiles). Sometimes the result rendered frames of the first (GPU) scene are corrupted, showing bright spaces instead of dark ones, but most of the time they are OK. The other (CPU) scene is rendered fine. The following 2 consecutive rendered frames are an illustration of the problem:[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Later on I rendered again only the corrupted frames and most of them came out OK. What am I doing wrong, or is it a bug of Blender? Windows 10? Thank you.

Comment: I'm quite familiar with those errors. In my case rendering with multiple GPUs they get quite hot, I attribute the errors to that... but it might be something else. The errors are random so I can't point them to any particular issue with the scene. The only solution I've found is to always render as image sequences. If any frames are corrupt I delete them and re-render. You can just uncheck the box for "overwrite" in the output section that way only the deleted frames will be re-rendered.

Comment: Cegaton, Thank you again for your informative answer. I am relieved to read your explanation, and intend to always render image sequences and let my computer cool down a bit during long rendering sessions. PS, is there a way to upvote comments?